# How do I compose a new document in a specific (shared) folder

Tags: quip

New to Quip. Whenever I compose a new document, it's placed in my `Private` folder. I've searched high and low and cannot figure out how to compose the new document in the (shared) folder where I want it to live. Surely this can be done. What am I missing?

Comment: You share it: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000355165&type=1

Comment: Thanks for the input @identigral but that's something else. I know that I can move/share it. I want to cut out this unwanted step and create the document right where I want it to live (the already shared folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I've found is to go into folders and click **into** the folder that you want the document to live in. At that point, your screen should show you in that folder directory.

[image]

Now, when you click compose from this context, the pop-up will give you an option to

- Create in Private
- Create in Folder you're currently in (default as selected)

[image]

Otherwise, the document you compose will be in private.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new shared folder, and add users to the new folder, you will see an option to create a new document/folder/spreadsheet/message in the folder itself.

[image]